# Determine what program is in my MBR code

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, mbr

I've done a lot of partitioning / dual booting on my Macbook Pro. Right now I have Mac OS X installed along with Ubuntu 12.04, with Grub installed on the Ubuntu partition.

I am wondering - what is the code in my MBR (the first 446 bytes)? Because Macs use EFI and GUID partitioning, the MBR is only a protective/hybrid MBR (in my case, it is a hybrid MBR).

**Q: How can I identify what program is in my MBR** (based on its hexdump)? Is there some sort of a signature? **I'm guessing it's grub** but I did a [hexdump](http://pastebin.com/n9rMnPJc) of it and it didn't match the code I found in [this article](http://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/mbr/GRUB.htm) detailing the Grub MBR ("Stage 1") code.

EDIT: I am runnning rEFInd, an EFI bootmanager program. It is an EFI application, and thus resides on my EFI system partition. This program is what runs immediately following bootup, but I do not think it places any code in the 446 bytes of the MBR.

EDIT2: I should add that I have had Windows installed for dual-boot as well.

Comment: Why not simply booting from it to find out?

Comment: @michas Sorry, I guess I forgot to mention: I am runnning rEFInd, an EFI bootmanager program. It is an EFI application, and thus resides on my EFI system partition. This program is what runs immediately following bootup, but I do not think it places any code in the 446 bytes of the MBR. I will add this to the question.

Comment: I think I've found the answer: I believe it is Windows boot code. Based on the readable ASCII in the hexdump ("`Invalid partition table.Error loading operating system.Missing operating system.`") I was able to do a Google search and found two sites which discussed windows bootloaders. The hexdump of mine matches parts of the Win2k bootloader as well as the bootloader of one of the posters in the forum. See: http://masm32.com/board/index.php?PHPSESSID=c12063bb6f07643c172876b9b1fb40c0&topic=431.30, and http://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/mbr/Win2kmbr.htm.

Comment: Actually more pertinent than both of the previous links is this one, which documents the Windows 7 MBR: http://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/mbr/W7MBR.htm#CODE. The MBR documented there (i.e., the Windows 7 MBR) is identical to mine, which makes sense, because I had installed Windows 7. I will post an answer to the question as soon as I can.

Answer (score 3):

I think I've found the answer: I believe it is Windows boot code. Based on the readable ASCII in the hexdump (`"Invalid partition table.Error loading operating system.Missing operating system."`) I was able to do a Google search and found a site which discussed windows bootloaders. The hexdump of mine matches the Windows 7 bootloader detailed at http://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/mbr/W7MBR.htm#CODE. This makes sense, because I have installed Windows 7 in the past on my computer.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to find out the MBR-technology is the [bootinfoscript](https://github.com/arvidjaar/bootinfoscript) that was originally published on [Source Forge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/).

As it seems bytes `0x80` and `0x81` can be used to identify the MBR-Code:

```bash
  case ${Bytes80_to_81} in
    0069) BST='ISOhybrid (Syslinux 3.72-3.73)';;
    010f) BST='HP Recovery';;
    019d) BST='BSD4.4: FAT32';;
    0211) BST='Dell Utility: FAT16';;
    0488) BST="Grub2's core.img";;
```

[bootinfoscript#L2595](https://github.com/arvidjaar/bootinfoscript/blob/71f6c5cb0d81bc74cca3d3af9e770357868b3029/bootinfoscript#L2595)

The following command reads bytes `0x80` and `0x81` from disk:

```bash
sudo hexdump -v -s 0x80 -n 2 -e '2/1 "%x" "\n"' /dev/sdXY
#   hexdump - ASCII, decimal, hexadecimal, octal dump
#       -v               => Cause hexdump to display all input data.
#       -s offset        => Skip offset bytes from the beginning of the input.
#       -n length        => Interpret only length bytes of input.
#       -e format_string => Specify a format string to be used for displaying data:
#           2/1  => number of bytes substited by %x / iteration count for the whole format string.
#           "%x" => Will be substituted with bytes, number of bytes is specified by first number, here 2.
#           \n   => Append line break
#       /dev/sdXY        => Input file.
```

Source and case table in the [german ubuntuusers wiki](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/GRUB-Umgebung_analysieren/#GRUB-Version-in-MBR-oder-Partitions-Bootsektor-ermitteln).

Answer (score 2):

[The `ms-sys` utility](http://ms-sys.sourceforge.net/) can not only identify many variants of MBR and PBR boot codes, but also write them if needed.

```
Usage:
        ms-sys [options] [device]
Options:
    -1, --fat12     Write a FAT12 floppy boot record to device
    -2, --fat32nt5  Write a FAT32 partition NT5.0 boot record to device
    -8, --fat32nt6  Write a FAT32 partition NT6.0 boot record to device
    -x, --exfatnt6  Write a EXFAT partition NT6.0 boot record to device
    -e, --fat32pe   Write a FAT32 partition PE boot record to device
    -3, --fat32     Write a FAT32 partition DOS boot record to device
    -4, --fat32free Write a FAT32 partition FreeDOS boot record to device
    -5, --fat16free Write a FAT16 partition FreeDOS boot record to device
    -6, --fat16     Write a FAT16 partition DOS boot record to device
    -n, --ntfs      Write a NTFS partition Windows 7 boot record to device
    -o, --fat16ros  Write a FAT16 partition ReactOS boot record to device
    -c, --fat32ros  Write a FAT32 partition ReactOS boot record to device
    -q, --fat32kos  Write a FAT32 partition KolibriOS boot record to device
    -l, --wipelabel Reset partition disk label in boot record
    -p, --partition Write partition info (hidden sectors, heads and drive id)
                    to boot record
    -H, --heads <n> Manually set number of heads if partition info is written
    -B, --bps <n>   Manually set number of bytes per sector (default 512)
    -O, --writeoem <s>   Write OEM ID string <s> to file system
    -S, --writewds <x>   Write Windows Disk Signature hexadecimal <x> to MBR
    -7, --mbr7      Write a Windows 7 MBR to device
    -i, --mbrvista  Write a Windows Vista MBR to device
    -m, --mbr       Write a Windows 2000/XP/2003 MBR to device
    -9, --mbr95b    Write a Windows 95B/98/98SE/ME MBR to device
    -d, --mbrdos    Write a DOS/Windows NT MBR to device
    -s, --mbrsyslinux    Write a Syslinux MBR to device
    -t, --mbrgptsyslinux Write a Syslinux GPT MBR to device
    -a, --mbrreactos     Write a ReactOS MBR to device
    -k, --mbrkolibrios   Write a KolibriOS MBR to device
    -r, --mbrrufus  Write a Rufus MBR to device
    -g, --mbrgrub4dos    Write a Grub4Dos MBR to device
    -b, --mbrgrub2  Write a Grub 2 MBR to device
    -z, --mbrzero   Write an empty (zeroed) MBR to device
    -f, --force     Force writing of boot record
    -h, --help      Display this help and exit
    -v, --version   Show program version
    -w, --write     Write automatically selected boot record to device

    Default         Inspect current boot record

Warning: Writing the wrong kind of boot record to a device might
destroy partition information or file system!
```

Examples of use in inspection mode (typical results on a pure UEFI system):

```
# ms-sys /dev/sda                # MBR of an UEFI-bootable disk
/dev/sda has an x86 boot sector,
it is a zeroed non-bootable master boot record, like the one this
program creates with the switch -z on a hard disk device.

# ms-sys /dev/sda1              # PBR of an UEFI ESP
/dev/sda1 has a FAT32 file system.
/dev/sda1 has an x86 boot sector,
it is an unknown boot record
The OEM ID is mkfs.fat
```

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the first few KiB of the disk/partition to a file, and then let strings(1) or perhaps objdump(1) loose on that to find out what is in there.