# In a dual-boot system, what decides which MBR bootstraping code is used?

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, boot-loader, mbr

I am reading an article titled [*How Computers Boot Up*](https://manybutfinite.com/post/how-computers-boot-up/). In it, it suggests that a **Master Boot Record** (**MBR**) consists of "a tiny OS-specific bootstrapping program at the start of the MBR followed by a partition table for the disk".

It goes on to say that the OS-specific bootstrapping program could be "a Windows MBR loader, code from Linux loaders such as LILO or GRUB, or even a virus."

In a dual-boot system (e.g. Windows and Ubuntu), what factors determine which OS-specific bootstrapping program is used for the MBR?

N.B. This question is different from [Determine what program is in my MBR code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/61879/69099), which asks how to *identify* which program is in the MBR, whereas I'd like to know give two bootstrapping programs, what factors determine which one gets used.

Comment: Your dual boot system still uses one boot loader. For example, `grub` can boot either Windows or Linux.

Comment: I understand there's still just one boot program. But Windows uses Windows MBR, and Linux uses GRUB2. When I install Windows, it seems to overwrite whatever boot program I had installed previously, but it seems that not all OSes do this, so I am not sure if there's a convention as to which boot program is used. Is it the one from the last installed OS?

Comment: Correct, the boot loader used is the one last installed. Installers for systems such as Windows and Ubuntu typically install a boot loader without asking you. Therefore, if you were to install Windows last on a hard drive you had Linux on, the Windows boot loader will override whatever you had installed before. Some installers ask you if you want to install a boot loader or keep what you have, like Slackware.

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking of UEFI, where you can have multiple UEFI executables on the EFI partition, including GRUB2 and the Windows bootloader?